# XmlService getChild doesn't return named Element

Tags: google-apps-script

For some unknown reason, I can't make `getChild` work for a nested element.
Here's my sample Apps Script Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var document = XmlService.parse(CONTENT)
  var root = document.getRootElement()
  var rootNamespace = root.getNamespace()
  Logger.log('root name: %s\nroot namespace %s', root.getName(), root.getNamespace().getPrefix())
  var body = root.getChild('Body', rootNamespace)
  if (!body) throw 'Body is ' + body
  Logger.log('body name: %s\nbody namespace %s', body.getName(), body.getNamespace().getPrefix())
  var bodyNamespace = body.getNamespace()
  var resp = body.getChild('GetUserResponse', rootNamespace )
  if (!resp) throw 'resp is ' + resp
  Logger.log('resp name: %s\nresp namespace %s', resp.getName(), resp.getNamespace().getPrefix())
}

var CONTENT = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:TrackingId xmlns:h="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Customer/v13">80b3d5f3-95d7-4993-80cb-4363aad1e203</h:TrackingId>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetUserResponse xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Customer/v13">
      <User xmlns:a="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Customer/v13/Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        Dummy Data
      </User>
      <CustomerRoles xmlns:a="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Customer/v13/Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        Other Dummy Data
      </CustomerRoles>
    </GetUserResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>`
```

I've tried `getChild('GetUserResponse')` with no namespace argument, with parent element namespace argument but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you want has a different namespace than the root.

```
var userResponseNamespace = XmlService.getNamespace('https://bingads.microsoft.com/Customer/v13');
var resp = body.getChild('GetUserResponse', userResponseNamespace);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps.